# Advice on a design of a recursive method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, recursion

I have for example a Task class which can report how long a task would take to complete.  This class however can contain subtasks of the same type.

```
public class Task
 {
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public DateTime Finish {get; set;}
    public List<Task> SubTasks {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan GetDuration()
    {
        return Finish - Start;
    }

    public TimeSpan GetTotalDuration()
    {
        //How?
    }
 }
```

SubTasks can be several levels deep, there's no logical limit right now.  I'm not sure how to design the method responsible for walking the subtasks and accumulate the TimeSpan value?

Any elegant ideas appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: What would be your naive approach?

Comment: Is there any relation between durations of subtasks to the parent task, e.g. are they dependant on each other or should the duration of the parent task already contain the duration of all child tasks?

Comment: That would be another problem, just want to nail down the recursion first.  But to answer your question The parent start/finish time would be a min/max of the subtask dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd just do:

```
public TimeSpan GetTotalDuration()
{
    if (SubTasks != null)
        return GetDuration() + SubTasks.Sum(t => t.GetTotalDuration()); 

    return GetDuration();
}
```

Using Linq.

Edit: To handle the case where SubTasks is null (via Kristof's answer).

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but @Jackson Pope was faster... In my opinion this is the best and simplest way to achieve it. Recursive data should be solved with recursion. It can handle any number of levels of nesting.

Comment: @Fixer: Yes, it will. It will stack overflow eventually, but you'll need to go at least hundreds of levels before that would happen.

Comment: That's good to hear - on the surface it only looks like its iterating over the 1st level of subtasks.

Comment: @Fixer, it calls the same method on the SubTasks so it will look at their SubTasks too.

Comment: It is summing up the GetTotalDuration() for each task. And GetTotalDuration() method uses GetDuration() and then recursively sums up another GetTotalDuration(). So this code is awesome. Good work Jackson :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public TimeSpan GetTotalDuration()
    {
        var duration = GetDuration();
        if(SubTasks != null && SubTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var t in SubTasks)
            {
                duration += t.GetTotalDuration();
            }   
        }
        return duration;

    }
```